# Cascade drop-down in MVC View without ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, drop-down-menu, parameters, cascade

I created one View Model with two Entities. I am passing this view model to my MVC Razor view which have two html drop-downs for each entity respectively.

```
<select class="form-control" id="Employees" name="Employees">

    @foreach (var employee in Model.Employees)
     {
         <option value="@employee.Id"> @employee.name </option>
     }

</select>

<select class="form-control" id="Tasks" name="Tasks">

    @foreach (var task in Model.Tasks)
     {
         <option value="@task.Id"> @task.name </option>
     }

</select>
```

Employee table is the parent of Task table. What I want is getting all the tasks which are related to particular employee only. e.g. In Employee drop-down I select John, then in Tasks drop-down I should get all the tasks which are relative to John. I know how to do this with ajax. I am looking for some other solution.

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
@foreach (var task in Model.Tasks.Where(x=>x.employeeId == 'Selected in previous dropdown'))
 {
     <option value="@task.Id"> @task.name </option>
 }
```

Comment: You need to understand how the view is rendered. The `@foreach` loop you posted would be executed server side and only once. The only other way would be to render all the data into the page in some hidden manner and then populate the dropdowns via JS. This of course may not be viable if you have lots of data.

Answer (score 1):

Html block

```
<select id="Employees">
<option value="">Select Employee</option>
<option value="1">Employee1</option>
<option value="2">Employee2</option>
</select>

<select id="Tasks">
<option value="">Select Task</option>
<option value="1" data-employee="1">Employee1Task1</option>
<option value="2" data-employee="1">Employee1Task2</option>
<option value="3" data-employee="1">Employee1Task3</option>
<option value="1" data-employee="2">Employee2Task1</option>
<option value="2" data-employee="2">Employee2Task2</option>
<option value="3" data-employee="2">Employee2Task3</option>
</select>
```

Script scetion

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //on page ready hide all task option
            $("#Tasks").find('option').hide();
            // set task as empty
            $("#Tasks").val('');

            // onchange of employee Drop down
            $("#Employees").on('change', function () {
                var selectedEmployee = $("#Employees").val();
                if (selectedEmployee != '') {
                    $("#Tasks").find('option').hide();
$("#Tasks option[value='']").show();
                    $('*[data-employee="' + selectedEmployee + '"]').show();
                }
                else {
                    // if employee not selected then hide all tasks 
                    $("#Tasks").find('option').hide();
                    $("#Tasks").val('');
                }

            });

        });
    </script>
```

Please populate country and state drop down list using MVC way by for each loop and use above script. The mandatory case is you have to render all cascade options

```
<select class="form-control" id="Employees" name="Employees">

    @foreach (var employee in Model.Employees)
    {
        <option value="@employee.Id"> @employee.name </option>
    }

</select>

<select class="form-control" id="Tasks" name="Tasks">

    @foreach (var task in Model.Tasks)
    {
        <option value="@task.Id" data-employee="@task.EmployeeId"> @task.name </option>
    }

</select>
```